# Read a CSV from github into R

Tags: r, data-manipulation, data-management

I am trying to read a CSV from github into R:

```
latent.growth.data <- read.csv("https://github.com/aronlindberg/latent_growth_classes/blob/master/LGC_data.csv")
```

However, this gives me:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") : unsupported URL scheme
```

I tried `?read.csv`, `?download.file`, `getURL` (which only returned strange HTML), as well as the [data import manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-data.html), but still cannot understand how to make it work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(RCurl)
x <- getURL("https://raw.github.com/aronlindberg/latent_growth_classes/master/LGC_data.csv")
y <- read.csv(text = x)
```

You have two problems:

1. You're not linking to the "raw" text file, but Github's display version (visit the URL for https:\raw.github.com....csv to see the difference between the [raw version](https://raw.github.com/aronlindberg/latent_growth_classes/master/LGC_data.csv) and the [display version](https://github.com/aronlindberg/latent_growth_classes/blob/master/LGC_data.csv)).
2. https is a problem for R in many cases, so you need to use a package like `RCurl` to get around it. In some cases (not with Github, though) you can simply replace https with http and things work out, so you can always try that out first, but I find using RCurl reliable and not too much extra typing.

Comment: How do you resolve `Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate`?

Comment: Can also be written as one line for memory/space purposes:

`y <- read.csv(text=getURL("https://raw.github.com/aronlindberg/latent_growth_classes/master/LGC_data.csv"))`

Comment: I tried this but it did not work. ```x <- getURL("https://github.com/eparker12/nCoV_tracker/blob/master/input_data/coronavirus_today.csv")
y <- read.csv(text = x)```

Comment: @Ben10, you're not using the raw URL. Can you try with that and see if it works?

Answer (score 26):

From the documentation of `url`:

> Note that ‘https://’ connections are not supported (with some
>        exceptions on Windows).

So the problem is that R does not allow conncetions to `https` URL's.

You can use `download.file` with `curl`:

```
download.file("https://raw.github.com/aronlindberg/latent_growth_classes/master/LGC_data.csv", 
    destfile = "/tmp/test.csv", method = "curl")
```

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel although it does depend on having Curl installed

Answer (score 23):

I am using R 3.0.2 and this code does the job.

```
urlfile<-'https://raw.github.com/aronlindberg/latent_growth_classes/master/LGC_data.csv'
dsin<-read.csv(urlfile)
```

and this as well

```
urlfile<-'https://raw.github.com/aronlindberg/latent_growth_classes/master/LGC_data.csv'
dsin<-read.csv(url(urlfile))
```

**edit (sessionInfo)**

```
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Polish_Poland.1250  LC_CTYPE=Polish_Poland.1250   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Polish_Poland.1250 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=Polish_Poland.1250    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.0.2
```

Comment: Quote from `?url`: Note that the ‘https://’ URL scheme is not supported except on Windows.

Answer (score 15):

In similar style to akhmed, I thought I would update the answer, since now you can just use Hadley's `readr` package. 
Just one thing to note: you'll need the url to be the **raw** content (see the `//raw.git...` below).
Here's an example:

```
library(readr)
data <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RobertMyles/Bayesian-Ideal-Point-IRT-Models/master/Senate_Example.csv")
```

Voilà!

Answer (score 8):

Realizing that the question is very old, Google still reported it as a top result (at least for me) so I decided to provide the answer for year 2015.

Folks are generally migrating now to `curl` package (including famous `httr`) as described [by r-bloggers](http://www.r-bloggers.com/the-curl-package-a-modern-r-interface-to-libcurl/) which offers the following very simple solution:

```
library(curl)

x <- read.csv( curl("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/trinker/dummy/master/data/gcircles.csv") )
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what I've been helping develop **rio** for. It's basically a universal data import/export package that supports HTTPS/SSL and infers the file type from its extension, thus allowing you to read basically anything using one import function:

```
library("rio")
```

If you grab the "raw" url for your CSV from Github,  you can load it one line with `import`:

```
import("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aronlindberg/latent_growth_classes/master/LGC_data.csv")
```

The result is a data.frame:

```
     top100_repository_name   month monthly_increase monthly_begin_at monthly_end_with
1                    Bukkit 2012-03                9              431              440
2                    Bukkit 2012-04               19              438              457
3                    Bukkit 2012-05               19              455              474
4                    Bukkit 2012-06               18              475              493
5                    Bukkit 2012-07               15              492              507
6                    Bukkit 2012-08               50              506              556
...
```

Comment: I try this and get `get_ext(file) : file has no extension`

Comment: @Adrian There was a small typo in the most recent Github version. Either install the older version from CRAN or reinstall from Github and it should work for you.

Comment: Thanks - problem is fixed.  Your solution is the only one that worked for me (Windows 8.1)

Answer (score 2):

Seems nowadays GitHub wants you to go through their API to fetch content. I used the [gh](https://github.com/r-lib/gh) package as follows:

```r
require(gh)

tmp = tempfile()
qurl = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aronlindberg/latent_growth_classes/master/LGC_data.csv'
# download
gh(paste0('GET ', qurl), .destfile = tmp, .overwrite = TRUE)
# read
read.csv(tmp)
```

The important part is that you provide an personal access token (PAT). Either through the `gh(.token = )` argument, or as I did, by setting the PAT globally in an `~/.Renviron` file [1]. Of course you first have to create the PAT at your [GitHub account](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token).

[1] `~/.Renviron`, I guess is searched first by all [r-lib](https://github.com/r-lib) packages, as [gh](https://github.com/r-lib/gh) is one. The token therein should look like this:

```
GITHUB_PAT = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

---

You could also use the [usethis](https://usethis.r-lib.org/) package to set up the PAT.

Answer (score 0):

curl might not work in windows at least for me

This is what worked for me in Windows

```r
download.file("https://github.com/aronlindberg/latent_growth_classes/master/LGC_data.csv", 
    destfile = "/tmp/test.csv",method="wininet")
```

In Linux

```r
download.file("https://github.com/aronlindberg/latent_growth_classes/master/LGC_data.csv", 
    destfile = "/tmp/test.csv",method="curl")
```

Answer (score 0):

A rather dummy way... using copy/paste from clipboard

```
x <- read.table(file = "clipboard", sep = "t", header=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by other postings, just go to the link for the raw code on github.

For example:

```r
x <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2018/2018-04-23/week4_australian_salary.csv")
```