# R produces "unsupported URL scheme" error when getting data from https sites

Tags: r, knitr

R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16) for Windows 8 `knitr` version 1.5  Rstudio 0.97.551

I am using `knitr` to do the markdown of my R code.
As part of my analysis I downloaded various data sets from the web, `knitr` is totally fine with getting data from http sites but from https ones where it generates an `unsupported URL scheme` message. 
I know when using the `download.file` function on a mac the `method` parameter has to be set to `curl` to get data from an https however this doesn't help when using `knitr`.

What do I need to do so that `knitr` will gather data from Https websites?

Edit: 
Here is the code chunk that returns an error in Knitr but when run through R works without error.

````
```{r}
fileurl <- "https://dl.dropbox.com/u/7710864/data/csv_hid/ss06hid.csv"
download.file(fileurl, destfile = "C:/Users/xxx/yyy")
```
````

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read a CSV from github into R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14441729/read-a-csv-from-github-into-r)

Comment: @Thomas thank you for the suggestion however this problem is not about getting R to read a file from a website, it is about getting Knitr to express the R code that reads a data file from a website. Using windows it is not an issue accessing Https sites with R however if you write markdown code with Knitr it becomes a problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Edit (May 2016)*: As of R 3.3.0, `download.file()` should handle SSL websites automatically on all platforms, making the rest of this answer moot.

You want something like this:

```
library(RCurl)
data <- getURL("https://dl.dropbox.com/u/7710864/data/csv_hid/ss06hid.csv",
               ssl.verifypeer=0L, followlocation=1L)
```

That reads the data into memory as a single string. You'll still have to parse it into a dataset in some way. One strategy is:

```
writeLines(data,'temp.csv')
read.csv('temp.csv')
```

You can also separate out the data directly without writing to file:

```
read.csv(text=data)
```

Edit: A much easier option is actually to use the **rio** package:

```
library("rio")
import("https://dl.dropbox.com/u/7710864/data/csv_hid/ss06hid.csv")
```

This will read directly from the HTTPS URL and return a data.frame.

Comment: When I loaded the RCurl package and subsituted in your code into the Knitr markdown file then knitted it to HTML it all worked perfectly, so thank you very much!

Answer (score 21):

You could use https with download.file() function by passing "curl" to method as :

```
download.file(url,destination,method="curl")
```

Answer (score 9):

Use `setInternet2(use = TRUE)` before using the `download.file()` function. It works on Windows 7.

```
setInternet2(use = TRUE)
download.file(url, destfile = "test.csv")
```

Answer (score 5):

I am sure you have already found solution to your problem by now.

I was working on an assignment right now and ended up getting the same error. I tried some of the tricks, but that did not work for me. Maybe because I am working on Windows machine.

Anyhow, I changed the link to http: rather than https: and that did the trick.

Following is chunk of my code:

```
if (!file.exists("./PeerAssesment2")) {dir.create("./PeerAssessment2")}
fileURL <- "http://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/repdata%2Fdata%2FStormData.csv.bz2"
download.file(fileURL, dest = "./PeerAssessment2/Data.zip")

install.packages("R.utils")
library(R.utils)
if (!file.exists("./PeerAssessment2/Data")) {
    bunzip2 ("./PeerAssessment2/Data.zip", destname = "./PeerAssessment2/Data")
}
list.files("./PeerAssessment2")

noaaData <- read.csv ('./PeerAssessment2/Data')
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue with knitr and download.file() with a https url, on Windows 8.

You could try `setInternet2(TRUE)` before using the `download.file()` function. However I'm not sure that this fix works on Unix-like systems.

```
setInternet2(TRUE)  # set the R_WIN_INTERNET2 to TRUE
fileurl <- "https://dl.dropbox.com/u/7710864/data/csv_hid/ss06hid.csv"
download.file(fileurl, destfile = "C:/Users/xxx/yyy") # now it should work
```

*Source :* R documentation (`?download.file()`) :

> Note that https:// URLs are only supported if --internet2 or environment variable R_WIN_INTERNET2 was set or setInternet2(TRUE) was used (to make use of Internet Explorer internals), and then only if the certificate is considered to be valid.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a https with the following code running perfectly in R and getting      `unsupported URL scheme` when knitting to html:

```
temp = tempfile()
download.file("https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/repdata%2Fdata%2Factivity.zip", temp)
data = read.csv(unz(temp, "activity.csv"), colClasses = c("numeric", "Date", "numeric"))
```

I tried all the solutions posted here and nothing worked, in my absolute desperation I just eliminated the "s" in the "https" in the url and everything got fine...

Answer (score 1):

Using the R **download** package takes care of the quirky details typically associated with file downloads.  For you example, all you needed to do would have been:

````
```{r}
library(download)
fileurl <- "https://dl.dropbox.com/u/7710864/data/csv_hid/ss06hid.csv"
download(fileurl, destfile = "C:/Users/xxx/yyy")
```
````