# Error when knitr has to download a zip file

Tags: r, curl, zip, knitr, rstudio

Due to clash with the network security system the only way I cand download a data file from the internet to an area in the network where it can be used in R it is by downloading it through R itself. When I run the script in RStudio it works fine. When I try to knit the script I will get either the message `Unsupported URL` or I will get

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection 
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withVisible -> eval -> eval -> read.csv -> 
    read.table -> file
Execution halted
```

below is the code that works under normal running but not during the knitting process.

```
url <- "https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/repdata%2Fdata%2Factivity.zip"
download.file(url, "repdata-data-activity.zip")
unzip("repdata-data-activity.zip")
```

If the file wasn't a zip I could download it using `RCurl`, but when I tried that R crashed, I have also tried `method = "curl", setInternet2(TRUE)`, and trying to remove the `s` from `https` but none of them have worked.

The result is that I cannot produce a knitted document which is a problem. I have previous on a very similar problem ( a CSV file not a zipped CSV file, see link below) and have tried the advice but without success: [R produces "unsupported URL scheme" error when getting data from https sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890633/r-produces-unsupported-url-scheme-error-when-getting-data-from-https-sites)

I am using Windows 7 and RStudio

To repeat: this is ONLY a problem WHEN KNITTING the document, not when running the script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was both the https and that the file is a binary. By changing the URL to http and setting file.download to mode="wb" the problem was resolved and the script could be knitted successfully.

Final code chunk is as follows

```
url <- "http://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/repdata%2Fdata%2Factivity.zip"
download.file(url, "repdata-data-activity.zip", mode="wb")
unzip("repdata-data-activity.zip")
```