# knitr returns error on read.csv, works fine on console

Tags: r, knitr, read.csv

I am trying to knit a document but I am getting an error on the read.csv function which works fine if I run it from the RMarkdown or from the console.

I have searched but could only find solutions related to reading a csv from a URL.
[R read.csv from URL error in knitr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28997402/r-read-csv-from-url-error-in-knitr)

````
```{r}
# This analysis uses the National Names dataset
national_names_raw <- read.csv("NationalNames.csv")
```
````

This is the error I get...

```
Quitting from lines 33-35 (Popularity_of_Kier.Rmd) 
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withVisible -> eval -> eval -> read.csv -> read.table -> file
Execution halted
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like `read.csv()` can't find the file. Is the CSV file in the same directory as the .Rmd file you are knitting? You could also try using an absolute filepath instead of a relative one.

Comment: To second the above comment, it is probable that `knitr` is running in a different directory than NationalNames.csv. Try adding the absolute path to check this. If this is the problem, then either keep the path, or figure out the directory in which `knitr` is running and set up a relative path from there.

Comment: You guys got it.  I put in an absolute reference and it worked. Thanks