# Error in reading URL in R

Tags: r

I would like to read a URL (csv file) online in R but my code does not work

```
test = read.csv('https://s3.amazonaws.com/folder/abcd/file.csv')
```

Here is the error: **Error in file(file, "rt") : for https:// URLs use setInternet2(TRUE)**

I have no idea how to fix this.Really appreciate any help

Comment: Error message suggests what to do: `setInternet2(TRUE)`

Comment: I tried that but it did not fix the error

Comment: Did you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299220) and [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14441729)?

Comment: Can you retrieve the file in a web browser?

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests a network constraint (e.g., you are attempting to access the AWS S3 bucket from your work location...but the SysAdmins have locked that protocol/port/etc. down).

If you are attempting to download a specific file, then you could download the file outside of R (say, using cURL), save it on your hard drive, then modify read.csv to access the file from your workstation.

If you need to [programmatically] access multiple files for download, then it's to your advantage to research 'setInternet2' (an MS-Windows DLL) AND existence of any network access limitations imposed by your organization's SysAdmins.