# How to retrieve a tsv file from github directly to my R session?

Tags: r, github

So, I have tsv file consisting of a single column that I would like to retrieve from github to my R session, and read it as a data frame. Is there a simple way to do this? 
Thank you in advance for any answers

Comment: Have you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14441729/read-a-csv-from-github-into-r)?

Comment: yes, I tried it but from it isn't working for my tsv file, I used it like this:
x <- getURL("https://raw.github.com/tadeu95/BAGs/bold_data.txt")

y <- read.tsv(text = x)

Comment: `getURL("https://github.com/tadeu95/BAGs/blob/master/bold_data.txt")`