# cannot run ggplotly on a geom_col

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly, geom-col

This is the data https://github.com/Clairinechendra/sbucks1010/blob/main/p3.csv

Below is my code

```
p3_plot <- p3 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x= size_ml, y= n, fill= category))+
  geom_col(position="stack") +
  theme_light()

ggplotly(p3_plot)
```

everytime i run the ggplotly it doesn't work even though i already import the library plotly. any solutions for this?

Comment: This code works for me. Maybe check to see if you have any package conflicts or if any package needs to be updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately "it doesn't work" doesn't say much about *what* didn't work and *how* it didn't work (did you get an an error? A warning? A blank plot? No data? Or ...?)

Below is a fully reproducible example. Please do a clean restart of R/RStudio (don't restore an older session), and then copy & paste the code below to verify that you can reproduce the plot.

```r
library(tidyverse)

p3 <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Clairinechendra/sbucks1010/main/p3.csv")
p3_plot <- p3 %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = size_ml, y = n, fill = category))+
    geom_col(position = "stack") +
    theme_light()

library(plotly)
ggplotly(p3_plot)
```

[image]

Two additional comments speculating as to the issue(s) you're having:

1. Perhaps the issue was with trying to read the CSV directly through the link you give at the beginning of the post: if you read data from GitHub, [make sure you read data as "raw" data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14441729/read-a-csv-from-github-into-r) (see the revised link I use inside `read_csv`).
2. As an intermediate step, always inspect the `ggplot` object (here: `p3_plot`) prior to "plotly-fication". If that plot is empty/wrong, the issue is not with `plotly`.